# xcode8 archive iPhone debug APP first can't install

Tags: ios, xcode8, archive

When I archive first the App can't install. Without changing anything do archive again the App gets installed fine on iPhone. I have no clue how to fix this behavior. Any suggestions what happens and how to fix it?

[image: This is step btn]

Comment: if you want to archive for test, you should create `Ad Hoc` `pp ` file first, when you archive you should choose `Save for Ad Hoc Deployment`, if you want to archive for upload to App Store, you should create `App Store pp` file, there choose `Save for iOS App Store Deployment`.

Comment: thanks, i kown this way and using this at previous job. now i want to try the i say method. beacues at document say the two method have same function.

Comment: did you  try the second choose method? did it work for you ?

Comment: i used the second choose in previous company, it can be used. at now i want to konw the question at used the fourth choose. because the two method almost the same as document explain. just one using debug certificate and one using release certificate

Answer (score 0):

There are difirrent between `Save for Ad Hoc Deployment` and `Save for Development Deployment`， although they are all available for the `UDID`s you add in your development account.

The diffirent is The `Save for Ad Hoc Deployment` is signed with the distribution certificate(Ad Hoc distribution file).

However, `Save for Development Deployment` is code signed with your development certificate.

So, you should make sure of your certificate if is use correct.

**Edit -1**

And, check your certificate if is valid in `developer.apple.com`.

Comment: yes, the certificate is use correct. i don't used xcode automatically manage signing function. so the certificate is using my setting certificate. this question at this  first archive can't used, don't change anything just do again  archive can be used !

Comment: now i just reset my certificate use second choose before find the cause

Comment: @Mr_Bai, you go to `developer.apple.com` to make sure the certificate if is valid.

Comment: I'm sure the certificate is valid, now i have make a Ad Provisioning Profiles  using to archive and connect iphone test app using debug provisioning. i will using the Ad provisioning to archive before find the cause.